# I want to add a user queue on a html site using a python flask webserver

Tags: html, python-3.x

I wanted to make a queue on a web server using flask on python 3.7. Were it would have the first user wait 5 minutes and then the second user waits 10 minutes and the third user waits 15 minutes ect.

I am also quite new to python.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried much as i haven't managed to find anything. other than a simple timer that redirects after 5 min but its that same for all people and resets when reloading.